# Move last two episodes from directory in Python?

Tags: python

So, let's say I have 10 files in a directory, they are named:

```
N 221
N 222
N 225
N 227
N 228
P 09
P 10
P 11
```

I was able to extract the name ("N", "P") and the episode numbers. However, I am unable to figure out a good way to figure out the last two episodes of each series and then move the rest of the folders into an "old" folder. Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I assume you have a list

```
episodes = [("N", 221), ("N", 222), ("N", 225), ("N", 227),
            ("N", 228), ("P", 9), ("P", 10), ("P", 11)]
```

An easy way to filter out the last two episodes for each base name is to use a combination of `itertools.groupby()` and `collections.deque()`:

```
new_episodes = []
for name, it in groupby(episodes, lambda x: x[0]):
    new_episodes.extend(deque(it, maxlen=2))
```

This code results in `new_episodes` being

```
[('N', 227), ('N', 228), ('P', 10), ('P', 11)]
```

This assumes that the list `episodes` is sorted.